# Java JDBC Nullpointer when inserting

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, insert

Whenever I try to insert values into a table with jdbc, I get a nullpointer and I simply cannot figure out why.

It should work like this: I enter data into a text field on the JSP. When I press the submit button, the servlet should send the parameters from the text field to the data access class. The connection to the database works, as I can select * from x as a simple test. The strings should be added to the following SQL table:

```
create table bedrijf(
bedrijfID           int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
naam    varchar(80) not null,
postcode                varchar(10),
gemeente                varchar(50),
website            varchar(50),
primary key (bedrijfID)
);
```

**JSP sending the parameters:**

```
<table id="indextabel">
            <form action="StartServlet" method="post">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="bedrijfnaam">Naam bedrijf</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bedrijfnaam" id="bedrijfnaam"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="postcode">Postcode</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="gemeente">Gemeente</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="gemeente" id="gemeente"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="website">Website</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="website" id="website"/></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Registreer nu" name="nieuwbedrijf-validate"/></td>
                </tr>
            </form>

        </table>
```

**Data Access class:**

```
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Account;
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Alumnus;
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Bedrijf;
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Event;
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Inschrijving;
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Richting;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DABedrijf {
    private Connection connection = null;

  public DABedrijf(String url, String login, String password, String driver) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
      // Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Class.forName(driver);
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
  }

  public void close() throws SQLException {
    if (connection != null) {
      connection.close();
    }
  }

    public ArrayList<Bedrijf> getAlleBedrijven(){
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        ArrayList<Bedrijf> bedrijven = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from bedrijf order by bedrijf.naam");

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Bedrijf bedrijf = new Bedrijf();
                bedrijf.setBedrijfid(resultSet.getInt("bedrijf.bedrijfid"));
                bedrijf.setNaam(resultSet.getString("bedrijf.naam"));
                bedrijf.setPostcode(resultSet.getString("bedrijf.postcode"));
                bedrijf.setGemeente(resultSet.getString("bedrijf.gemeente"));
                bedrijf.setWebsite(resultSet.getString("bedrijf.website"));


                bedrijven.add(bedrijf);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {

                statement.close();

                if (resultSet != null) {
                    resultSet.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
        return bedrijven;
  }
      public boolean bedrijfInsert(String naam, String postcode, String gemeente, String website) {
        boolean resultaat = true;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = connection.prepareStatement("Insert into bedrijf values (null,?,?,?,?)");

            statement.setString(1, naam);
            statement.setString(2, postcode);
            statement.setString(3, gemeente);
            statement.setString(4, website);
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            resultaat = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
        }
        return resultaat;
    }
}
```

**Servlet:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package info.toegepaste.www;

import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Account;
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Bedrijf;
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Alumnus;
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Event;
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Inschrijving;
import info.toegepaste.www.beans.Richting;
import info.toegepaste.www.dataaccess.DAAccount;
import info.toegepaste.www.dataaccess.DAAlumnus;
import info.toegepaste.www.dataaccess.DABedrijf;
import info.toegepaste.www.dataaccess.DAEvent;
import info.toegepaste.www.dataaccess.DAInschrijving;
import info.toegepaste.www.dataaccess.DARichting;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@WebServlet(name = "StartServlet", urlPatterns = {"/StartServlet"}, 
        initParams = {
            @WebInitParam(name = "url", value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/lesson"),
            @WebInitParam(name = "login", value = "dba"),
            @WebInitParam(name = "password", value = "sql"),
            @WebInitParam(name = "driver", value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")})


public class StartServlet extends HttpServlet {



    private DAAccount daaccount = null;
    private DAAlumnus daalumnus = null;
    private DABedrijf dabedrijf = null;
    private DAEvent daevent = null;
    private DAInschrijving dainschrijving = null;
    private DARichting darichting = null;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            String url = getInitParameter("url");
            String password = getInitParameter("password");
            String login = getInitParameter("login");
            String driver = getInitParameter("driver");
            if (daaccount == null) {
                daaccount = new DAAccount(url, login, password, driver);
            }
            if (daalumnus == null) {
                daalumnus = new DAAlumnus(url, login, password, driver);
            }

            if (dabedrijf == null) {
                dabedrijf = new DABedrijf(url, login, password, driver);
            }
            if (daevent == null) {
                daevent = new DAEvent(url, login, password, driver);
            }
            if (dainschrijving == null) {
                dainschrijving = new DAInschrijving(url, login, password, driver);
            }
            if (darichting == null) {
                darichting = new DARichting(url, login, password, driver);
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            if (daaccount != null) {
                daaccount.close();
            }
            if (daalumnus != null) {
                daalumnus.close();
            }
            if (dabedrijf != null) {
                daevent.close();
            }
            if (dainschrijving != null) {
                dainschrijving.close();
            }
            if (darichting != null) {
                darichting.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;


        if (request.getParameter("registreer-button") != null) {
             ArrayList<Event> eventen = daevent.getAlleEventen();
             ArrayList<Bedrijf> bedrijven = dabedrijf.getAlleBedrijven();
             ArrayList<Richting> richtingen = darichting.getAlleRichtingen();

             request.setAttribute("eventen", eventen);
             request.setAttribute("bedrijven", bedrijven);
             request.setAttribute("richtingen", richtingen);

            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("registreer.jsp");
        } else if (request.getParameter("inlog-knop") != null) {
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("inlog.jsp");

        } else if (request.getParameter("nieuwbedrijf-validate") != null) {

            String naam = request.getParameter("bedrijfnaam");
            String postcode = request.getParameter("postcode");
            String gemeente = request.getParameter("gemeente");
            String website = request.getParameter("website");

            if(dabedrijf.bedrijfInsert(naam, postcode, gemeente, website));{
            ArrayList<Bedrijf> bedrijven = dabedrijf.getAlleBedrijven();
        request.setAttribute("bedrijven", bedrijven);
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("registreer.jsp");}

        } else if (request.getParameter("nieuwbedrijf-knop") !=null) {
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("nieuwbedrijf.jsp");

        } else if (request.getParameter("registreer-validatie") !=null) {

            int richtingid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("richting"));
            int bedrijfid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("bedrijf"));
            String voornaam = request.getParameter("voornaam");
            String achternaam = request.getParameter("achternaam");
            String emailprive = request.getParameter("emailprive");
            String afstudeerjaar = request.getParameter("afstudeerjaar");
           String date = request.getParameter("date");
           java.sql.Date dateConvert = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
           String inlognaam = request.getParameter("inlognaam");
           String paswoord = request.getParameter("paswoord");

           if(daaccount.accountInsert(inlognaam, paswoord));{
           ArrayList<Account> accounts = daaccount.getAlleAccounts();
            request.setAttribute("accounts", accounts);}
           rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("registratiegelukt.jsp");

//            if(daaccount.accountInsert(voornaam, date));{
//            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("registratiegelukt.jsp");
//            
//            } 
//            if(daalumnus.alumnusInsert(richtingid, bedrijfid, voornaam, achternaam, emailprive, afstudeerjaar, dateConvert));{
//      rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("registratiegelukt.jsp");}
//            } else {
//      request.setAttribute("fout", "Toevoegen alumni niet gelukt!");
//      rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
//    }

        }


        rd.forward(request, response);

    }
```

I have genuinely no clue what the problem is and any help is appreciated.

stack trace:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[StartServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet StartServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.registreer_jsp._jspService(registreer_jsp.java:135)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at info.toegepaste.www.StartServlet.processRequest(StartServlet.java:182)
    at info.toegepaste.www.StartServlet.doPost(StartServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Show the stacktrace please.

Comment: "I have genuinely no clue what the problem is". The stack trace should tell you where the NPE comes from, surely ?

Comment: I have added the warning list, however I didn't get any the wiser. Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: The stacktrace is quite descriptive. What do you have in StartServlet.java line 182

Comment: Thank you for your answers so far. I have edited the original post with the entire servlet. Line 182 is the   rd.forward(request, response);

Comment: It seems that all the given if statements conditions are skipped and the `rd` is still `null`, try to, log it.

Comment: @Phonebox or maybe (in addition to @chsdk) you don't have required mapping (for example, `registratiegelukt.jsp` for last `if` clause) and servlet container can't find it and returns null. [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher-java.lang.String-)

Comment: I think I might have found something: there was a typo in the jsp on one of the submit buttons, so the servlet couldn't handle that request as it didnt exist. Thank you all for your input, I appreciate it very much

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a method on an object that is null (`registreer_jsp.java:135)`,

Please debug to find where the null variable is, or just look at the jsp it should relatively obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in registreer.jsp file

The servlet dispatches request to this jsp.
While executing this jsp, it throws this exception.

In your web application folder in tomcat, try to find the registreer_jsp.java file and look for line no 135 in that file as it is the line that has problems